# Can't view my Compute Engine VM instances. Says 404

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to view my Compute Engine VM's via the console UI, but all I get is the text "Status: Not Found. Status code: 404.".

I can connect to it via `gcutil` command though.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough information to help you at this point. What address did you visit? Are you logged in with the same account via gcutil and in the browser?

Comment: Oh I just tried again just now, and I can see my instances again. How do I close this?

Comment: I've voted to close as off topic because it's not reproducible. Thanks for following up!

Comment: Thanks. I voted as well.